# How Interpret a JS string as a file or use string in Bundlebars

Tags: javascript

I am using Bundlebars, an excellent library for converting handlebars templates into static html using given data.

For example,

```
var data = {name: 'foo', location: 'bar'}
bb.compile('template.hbs', data)
```

However, it doesn't look like Bundlebars does the same for an html string (for example,

```
"<h1>Hello {{name}} </h1>"
```

So I have two radically different questions; either one will help:

1. Can you, without creating an actual file, encode an html file into a variable such that the variable itself is interpreted as a file? 
   [ I think Bundlebars tries to use the 'open' function to read the file].
2. Can Bundlebars be used with a string itself instead of a file to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Bundlebars be used with a string itself instead of a file to read?

Per the Bundlebars API page on GitHub, `.compile()` expects the first argument to be a filename, not a string of HTML and it doesn't show other APIs that could take a string of HTML.

I don't quite understand the relationship between Bundlebars and Handlebars (it looks like Bundlebars uses Handlebars internally), but the [handlebars API](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html) takes a string of HTML if you can use that instead.

You should be able to just `require('handlebars.js')` and use handlebars itself for the string data.  The module itself is already loaded by Bundlebars so it's already available and in the module cache.

---

> Can you, without creating an actual file, encode an html file into a
>   variable such that the variable itself is interpreted as a file? [ I
>   think Bundlebars tries to use the 'open' function to read the file].

I am not aware of any way in Javascript to create a virtual file attached to a specific filename.  If you were using node.js, you could create a custom stream, but you would need an interface that allowed you to pass it an already open stream, not just a filename string.  The issue is that when you pass in a filename string to Bundlebars it is eventually going to call `fs.readFile()` on it while will then call `fs.open()` and `fs.read()` and there are no built-in hooks to intercept all those system calls to keep them from going to the file system.

---

Hmmm new idea... I suppose you could replace `fs.readFile()` before you call `bb.compile()` with your own function that would detect a certain filename and substitute results without going to the file system.  This is obviously a giant hack and it depends upon the fact that you know that Bundlebars calls `fs.readFile()` so that's all you need to replace.

Warning, this is a giant hack (I'd suggest finding a better way to solve your issue):

```
(function(orig) {
   fs.readFile = function(path, options, cb) {
       // see if it looks like there is HTML in the path
       if (path.indexOf("<") !== -1 && path.indexOf(">") !== -1) {
          // treat this as a string of HTML
          setTimeout(function() {
              // call the completion callback with the path as the 
              // contents of the file
              cb(0, path);
          }, 1);
       } else {
           return orig.apply(fs, arguments);
       }
   };
})(fs.readFile);
```

Comment: Yeah thats where my curiosity started, really. I was wondering if there is a way or an object in JS that can be treated as it would a file.

Comment: @Darshan - added more to my answer about both your questions.  I did come up with one "hackish" idea.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I looked through the source code of bundlebars and it's because it will eventually use FS that I wanted to see if I could virtually create a file. I will be using this with node.js ( that's the end project). Would you mind directing me or telling me more about this creating a custom stream idea?

Comment: Also saw the giant hack portion - i might have to do that. "lol".

Comment: @Darshan - I added code for the giant hack.  It just looks to see if it looks like there's HTML in the path and, if so, it just returns that (asynchronously) as the file contents.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I ended up using your first suggestion: using Handlebars Itself to compile a string, and it's working just fine. Thank you.